# Segmented numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence

The sequence of segmented numbers or prime numbers of measurement ([OEIS A002048](http://oeis.org/A002048)) is the sequence of numbers such that each member is the smallest positive (greater than zero) number that can't be made of a sum of earlier consecutive numbers, with `a(0) = 1`.

#### Example

To calculate `a(7)` we first calculate `a(0->6) = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 14]`. we then start from zero and go through numbers until we find one that is not the sum of one or more consecutive numbers in the sequence.

```
1  = 1
2  = 2
3  = 1 + 2
4  = 4
5  = 5
6  = 2 + 4
7  = 1 + 2 + 4
8  = 8
9  = 4 + 5
10 = 10
11 = 2 + 4 + 5
12 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 5
13 = 5 + 8
14 = 14
15 = ????
```

Since fifteen cannot be made by summing any consecutive subsequence and every number smaller can be fifteen is the next number in the sequence. `a(7) = 15`

#### Task

Your task is to take a number (via standard methods) and output the nth term in this sequence (via standard output methods).  This is code-golf and you will be scored as such.

#### Test Cases

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 5
4 -> 8
5 -> 10
6 -> 14
7 -> 15
8 -> 16
9 -> 21
```

Answer (score 13):

### Haskell, <s>62</s> 58 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @xnor!

```
(x:y)#z=x:filter(`notElem`scanl(+)x z)y#(x:z)
([1..]#[]!!)
```

Sequence is 0-indexed.

Comment: I think you need two more bytes and surround the last line with `()` to make it a proper function.  The partial applied `!!` is an operator section and must be enclosed in `()` to make it a function. Without it's just a snippet that only becomes a function (or "value" to use strict Haskell terms) with the missing argument.

Comment: Beautiful method! The import seems like overkill though; ``filter(`notElem`scanl(+)x z)y`` should do.

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, <s>50</s> 49 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with input on STDIN:

```
segmented.pl <<< 7
```

`segmented.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
${$_-=$\}++for@F;1while${-++$\};++$#F<$_&&redo}{
```

### Explanation

`@F` contains the list of (negative) sums of consecutive numbers that end with the current last number. When a new number is discovered the list is extended with 0 and then all values are decreased by the new number maintaining the invariant.

Global `%::` is used as a hash mapping all (negative) numbers that have been seen (through `@F`) to a non-zero value.

`$\` is the current number and gets increased until it reaches a value not yet in `%::`.

By being a bit careful about the order in which everything happens no initialization is needed, `1` will automatically become the first number.

Since the size of `@F` is how many numbers have been generated it can be used as a halting condition

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḷß€Ẇ;ḅ1‘ḟ$Ṃ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bi2w5_igqzhuoY74biFMeKAmOG4nyThuYI&input=&args=OQ)

#### How it works

```
Ḷß€Ẇ;ḅ1‘ḟ$Ṃ  Main link. Argument: n

Ḷ            Unlength; yield [0, ..., n - 1].
 ß€          Recursively map the main link over the range.
   Ẇ         Window; yield all subarrays of consecutive elements of the result.
    ;        Append n to the array of subarrays.
     ḅ1      Convert all subarrays from base 1 to integer.
             This is equivalent to S€ (sum each), but it allows ; to hook.
         $   Combine the previous two links into a monadic chain.
       ‘       Increment all sums.
        ḟ      Filter; remove the original sums from the incremented ones.
          Ṃ  Compute the minimum.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](http://www.cp1252.com/)

```
Xˆ$µ>D¯ŒOså_i¼Dˆ
```

**Explanation**

```
Xˆ                # initialize global array to [1]
  $               # push 1 and input to stack
   µ              # while counter != input
    >             # increase variable on stack
      ¯ŒO         # list of all sums of consecutive number in global array
     D   så_i     # if current stack value is not in the list
             ¼    # increase counter
              Dˆ  # add current stack value to global array
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=WMuGJMK1PkTCr8WST3PDpV9pwrxEy4Y&input=OQ)

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)

Comment: Does `$` instead of `Xs` work?

Comment: @Adnan: Yes of course. Silly of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>19</s> 17 bytes

Damn off-by one ruining all my implicits. (Same bytes count, literaly incrementing `Q`: `=hQesmaYf!}TsM.:Y`)

```
esmaYf!}TsM.:Y)1h
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=esmaYf%21%7DTsM.%3AY%291h&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9&debug=0).

Comment: Using reduce saves (only) one byte. Expected more... `eu+Gf!}TsM.:G))hQY`

Comment: @Jakube map is usually shorter for self referential sequences like these

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, <strike>125</strike> <strike>112</strike> 110 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Neil

```js
f=n=>{a=[[]];for(i=1,z=0;z<=n;i++)a.some(b=>b.includes(i))||(a[z+1]=[0,...a[z++]||[]].map(v=>i+v));alert(i-1)}
```

*Previous answers*

112 bytes thanks to @Neil:

```js
f=n=>{a=[[]];for(i=1,z=0;z<=n;i++)if(!a.some(b=>b.includes(i))){a[z+1]=[0,...a[z++]||[]].map(v=>i+v)}alert(i-1)}
```

125 bytes:

```js
f=n=>{a=[[]];for(i=1,k=z=0;z<=n;i++)if(a.every(b=>b.every(c=>c-i))){a[i]=[i].concat((a[k]||[]).map(v=>i+v));k=i,z++}alert(k)}
```

Comment: For `b.every(c=>c-i)`,  I'd try `!b.includes(i)` or possibly `!a.some(b=>b.includes(i))` works, while `[0,...a[k]||[]].map(v=>i+v)` might replace `[i].concat((a[k]||[]).map(v=>i+v))`. Also do you really need `k`?

Comment: Now that your `if(!...){...}` is only one statement, you could probably replace it with `...||(...)` or `...?0:...`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>12</s></sup> 11 bytes

```
!¡ö←`-NmΣQø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr/23igoHhuKMxMP8hwqHDtuKGkGAtTm3Oo1HDuP//)

returns nth term, 1-indexed.

-1 byte from Dominic Van Essen, using empty list.

### Explanation

```
!¡ö←`-NmΣQø
          ø start with the empty list:
 ¡ö         apply the following infinitely:
         Q  get all subsequences
       mΣ   sum each of them
    `-N     remove the sums from natural numbers
   ←        take the first one
!           get the nth element from this list
```

Comment: You can start with the empty list, instead of 1, for [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr/23igoHhuKMxMP8hwqHDtuKGkGAtTm3Oo1HDuP//)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>113</s> <s>105</s> <s>92</s> 80 bytes

```
s=F={1}
x=1
exec"while{x}<=s:x+=1\nF={x+j for j in{0}|F};s|=F\n"*input()
print x
```

The final bytes I saved were inspired by Ton’s Perl answer: my `F` does the same thing as his `@F`; my `s` does essentially the same thing as his `%::`.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

```
(n,a=[],s=a,i=1)=>s[i]?f(n,a,s,i+1):--n?f(n,[0,...a].map(j=>s[j+=i]=j),s,i):i
```

Basically a recursive port of the algorithm of @TonHospel's Perl answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 97 bytes

```scala
n=>{var(r,i)=Seq(1)->1;while(r.size<n+1){i+=1;r++=Set(i)--r.tails.flatMap(_.inits).map(_.sum)};i}
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fRMtJxfqTz2xaWMkaYvgbQ)